# How to calculate the mean weight shortest path in a network

Tags: algorithm, networking, dijkstra

**Input**

I have an undirected graph G(V,E) with a set of vertices V and a set of edges E. Each edge has a positive weight w_ij. There is a starting node v_1 and an end node v_3.

**Problem/Algorithm**

Is it possible to find an "optimal" path, with optimal in the sense, that the weight per used edge in the path is minimized? Also no node should be visited more than once.

Note that the classical Dijkstra algorithm will fail, because it looks for the path with the least sum of weights: 
Min (Sum(w_ij))

However, I am looking for the path that satisfies: Min (Sum(w_ij)/number_of_edges)

**Example**

For clarification, I created a small figure. 
Red numbers correspond to weights of edges and black letters to labels of vertices.
If I calculate the shortest path between the vertex v1 and v3 (Picture 1) with the Dijkstra algorithm, the shortest path is v1->v2->v3, since
this gives the lowest total weight:

w = 2 + 2 = 4.

However, I would like to have the "mean weight shortest path length", such that the average weight per step of the path is lower than in every
 other path. In the above mentioned
example the "mean weight shortest path way" is v1->v4->v5->v6->v7->v3, since the mean weight would be

w = 1/5 (1+1+1+1+1) = 1,

whereas on the other path it is v1->v2->v3 gives

w = 1/2 (2+2) = 2.

[image]

**First Approach: Dijkstra** 
Just calculate all paths (without cycles) between start and end node. Then calculate the total weight and total length and divide them. This approach will take up too much memory for a decently sized network, which I ultimately have in mind (n=200000).

**Second Approach: Dijkstra with concurrent length calculation** 
While calculating the shortest path (minimum weight sum), you also save the length of the path so far. This way you know the current optimal path regarding weight per edge.

**Question**

1) Does a solution exist to solve this problem?

2) How to implement a solution to this problem?

Comment: _"1) Does a library exist to find the "mean weight shortest path length"?"_ => _`Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.`_. _"2) So far I used the Dijkstra algorithm of the Boost library for calculating the shortest path - is it possible to adapt it?"_ => _too broad_.

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm (in the best case an already existing library) that can solve my above problem. Apparently that was not clear enough. Now it is. I only mentioned boost, because I wanted to show what I previously tried. I also read though a bunch of literature (that turned unhelpful) regarding Dijkstra/Bellman-Ford/Floyd-Warshall/A*/Min-plus matrix multiplication. Now I am looking for help here. I don't think my question is too broad.

Comment: As mentioned your question is off-topic here for actually two reasons. You may refer to the help pages, if you have doubts. (Already 4 close votes registered for now, seem to improve my reasonings)

Comment: So, how should I improve my question or if this is alltogether the wrong place to ask it, where would be a better place for it? Do you have any advice? I am really lost on finding the right algorithm. If nothing happens, I will remove the question myself tomorrow, to spare others the hassle. I guess I am sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Ok, I removed the library comment. Please remove the on-hold. This question is purely about the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the cost function in Dijkstra's algorithm in order to make this work. For each node you should calculate the average you want (instead of the actual weight), and store and update it as you visit new nodes. You should store *two* quantities for each visited nodes: the `average_so_far` (instead of length of shortest path, as before) and `number_of_edges` (to keep track with how many edges are already in your path). If you know this for each already visited vertex, then once you  visit a new vertex, you should check whether the new average with one more edge `(average_so_far*number_of_edges+weight(new edge))/(number_of_edges+1)` is an improvement.

Something along these lines should eventually work.